# Wer darf Vorschläge für das "Unwort des Jahres" machen?

Tags: neologism

Mit großem Interesse verfolge ich jedes Jahr die Kür zum [*Unwort des Jahres*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unwort). Es gibt einen aktiven [Arbeitskreis](http://www.unwortdesjahres.uni-frankfurt.de/) an der Goethe Universität in Frankfurt am Main, der Vorschläge und Einsendungen sammelt, auswertet und veröffentlicht. Für das Jahr 2010 wurde *"alternativlos"* ausgewählt. Es heißt dort:

> Die Vorschläge können aus allen Bereichen der öffentlichen Kommunikation stammen, aus Politik, Verwaltung, Wirtschaft, Technik, Wissenschaft, Kulturinstitutionen oder Medien, und sollen in jedem Fall eine Quellenangabe enthalten.

Woher stammen diese Einsendungen und Vorschläge und wer darf mitmachen? Gibt es definierte Verfahrensregeln?

Comment: „alternativlos“ ist ja auch echt konkurrenzlos. ;-) Wobei, bei Pferdewetten kann so ein Alternativlos sicher auch praktisch sein.

Comment: Ich habe mir die alten Unwörter durchgelesen und bin schockiert.

"Ethnische Säuberung" stammt wirklich erst aus 1992 und war ein Euphemismus aus Jugoslawien?? Das empfinde ich als einen Fachbegriff und soo klein war ich 1992 auch noch nicht. Solche Euphemismen haben wohl eine Tendenz, ganz schnell den negativen Sinn des Beschriebenen anzunehmen,

Comment: @thei: Ähm, _Fachbegriff?_ Ich bin kein Fachmann, der das wirklich beurteilen könnte, aber _sauberer_ wird eine Region nach einer "ethnischer Säuberung" bestimmt nicht ...

Comment: @Hendrik: Im selben Sinn, in dem "Konzentrationslager" als Euphemismus der Täter eingeführt wurde und jetzt als schlimmer als Straflager empfunden wird. Wenn jemand sagt "Die Lager im Land X sind praktisch Konzentrationslager.", dann wird das sicher nicht als verharmlosend empfunden.

Comment: @thei: In einem Konzentrationslager werden viele Menschen auf engem Raum konzentriert, und zwar in einem Lager. Also ist der Begriff per se treffend. Das ist bei "ethnischer Säuberung" ganz anders, meine ich. Nur diejenigen können auf "säubern" kommen, die die Region ohne die fragliche Volksgruppe als "sauberer" empfinden.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Laut [Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unwort#Unwort_des_Jahres_.28Deutschland.29) darf jeder Vorschläge machen:

> Das Unwort des Jahres wird seit 1994 jährlich von der Jury der sprachkritischen Aktion „Unwort des Jahres” an der Universität Frankfurt am Main bestimmt. **Hierzu kann aber jeder Vorschläge einreichen.** Bis 1994 wurde das „Unwort des Jahres” im Rahmen der Gesellschaft für deutsche Sprache (GfdS) gewählt. Nach einem Konflikt mit dem Vorstand der GfdS machte sich die Jury als „Sprachkritische Aktion Unwort des Jahres” selbständig.[2]

Siehe: http://www.unwortdesjahres.uni-frankfurt.de/

In der Satzung steht u.a.:

> **Grundsätze der Aktion »Unwort des Jahres«**
>
> [...] Für die Aktion ist wesentlich, dass jeweils die ganze Sprachgemeinschaft aufgerufen wird, sich an der Unwort-Wahl zu beteiligen. Jeder Bürger und jede Bürgerin kann Vorschläge machen.

Vorschläge an: vorschlaege@unwortdesjahres.net

Comment: @Takkat Es steht "die Vorschläge", sprich die *Wörter* können aus den Bereichen stammen, nicht die Leute, die einreichen dürfen. :)

Answer (score 3):

Wie es aussieht, kann das [jeder](http://www.uni-frankfurt.de/fb/fb10/IDLD/ehemalige_histSprw/Schlosser/unwortdesjahres/kontakt/index.html).